# Jyotisha-Shastra and prediction about death?

Tags: astrology, death

Does Jyotisha-Shastra  have elaborate methods to predict death? If so, what is the method? I read in "Jaimini sutra" pertaining to astrology that there is a predictive method for death, but the method is unclear. Also, I do not understand whether it is credible.

Comment: Your Q needs to be more clear.Are u asking about does Jyotisha predict the nature of a particular native's death?Or Does Jyptisha predict early,premature deaths etc...?Or do the Jyotisha texts discuss omens that indicate forthcoming death?

Comment: @Rickross All the questions you ask are my questions

Comment: Oh yes, there are very detailed methods but considering that that is such a sensitive topic, these methods should not be discussed in such forums